# CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes crashing app on line breaks

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Code:

```
NSString* string3 = (NSString*)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)tvQ.text, NULL, (CFStringRef)@":/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

My code is working to pass special characters properly via URL to my database, however, if I insert data with linebreaks, it seems to break my app and crashes. Any ideas?

**code was provided to me by user "tc." from a previous question. This is a different issue, so I started a new question.

Figured out the answer:

```
NSString* encoded = [[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" "] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"ç" withString:@"c"];
NSString* string3 = [(NSString*)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)encoded, NULL, (CFStringRef)@":/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=", kCFStringEncodingUTF8) autorelease];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you should parse the string before calling CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes...

A good idea is probably to use NSMutableString's method

```
replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:
```

Comment: how do I use that and the CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes in the same declaration of string3?

Answer (score 0):

1. Inside the [NSString class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003744), there is a section named 
   **Working with URLs**.

   - stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
   - stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
2. The parameters for url works by the form:

   param1 = value1 & param2 = value2 ....

   Your **sub** has no value, maybe it should be removed from the param list.